# Knockout foreach afterRender

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, slider

how can I call afterRender after generating all foreach elements? I want to initialize slider after rendering all slides.

I've tried:

```
<div class="order__picker-dates owl-carousel" data-bind="foreach: deliveryDays, afterRender: renderedDelivery">
  <div class="slide">...</div>
</div>
```

but put console.log(jQuery('.slide').length) in renderedDelivery function. Sometimes it writes 0 elements, sometimes all generated. renderedDelivery fires ones.